# Parsing multiple entries in multiple CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv, for-loop

Hope someone can offer a suggestion to help me speed up a Powershell script. What I am doing is reading in hundreds of CSV files, parsing the information to get data about missing entries, and then writing that output to a HTML file. Here is the loop that I am using to process the files:

```
ForEach ($Filename in $FileList) {
    $CustTemp = import-csv "$FilePath\$Filename"
    $CustName = $CustTemp[0].CustName
    Write-Host "Reading data for $CustName"`r
    For ($counter=0;$counter -lt 31;$counter++){
        $CheckDate = (get-date).AddDays(-$counter)
        $CheckShortDate = $CheckDate.ToShortDateString()
        $TempData = import-csv "$FilePath\$Filename" | Select FileName,FileDate | where {$_.FileDate -eq $CheckShortDate}
        If ($TempData -eq $null) {
            $row = "No file found for $CheckShortDate for $CustName"
            $HTMLReportItems += $row
        }
    $HTMLReportItems = $HTMLReportItems | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
    }
}
```

This loop worked fine when I was testing with a few CSV files but when running it against a large number of files (300+) the loop is taking an extremely long time to complete for each file (30s-1m). I'm pretty sure the reason why is that the CSV file is being accessed 30 times per iteration. What I am hoping is that someone will have a better suggestion on how I can process the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading `$FilePath\$Filename` multiple times. Read it outside the `for` loop and only do the filtering inside. Move the HTML generation outside the loop as well.

```
$HTMLReportItems = foreach ($Filename in $FileList) {
  $csv = Import-Csv (Join-Path $FilePath $Filename)
  $CustName = $csv[0].CustName
  $data = $csv | select FileName,FileDate

  Write-Host "Reading data for $CustName"

  for ($counter=0;$counter -lt 31;$counter++){
    $CheckShortDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$counter).ToShortDateString()
    $TempData = $data | ? {$_.FileDate -eq $CheckShortDate}
    if ($TempData -eq $null) {
        "No file found for $CheckShortDate for $CustName"
    }
  }
}

$HTMLReportItems = $HTMLReportItems | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. After making the change I am still seeing strange behavior. Each iteration is taking longer than the next. Here's the output from my trial run with 10 CSV files:

Start time: 17:53:30

Reading: ab010 time:  00.6093750
Reading: ak007 time:  01.7968750
Reading: ak036 time:  02.9218750
Reading: az052 time:  04.1562500
Reading: az106 time:  05.2187500
Reading: az141 time:  06.4531250
Reading: az159 time:  07.6103516
Reading: ca017 time:  08.8593750
Reading: ca051 time:  10.0468750
Reading: ca136 time:  11.5166015
Processing complete.
Total time:  59.3300781 sec.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting in my response. Each time it read a file it took approx. 1 sec. longer than the previous file. Iterating through 300+ files this way would take way too long to be practical.  Each CSV contains approx. 50 rows so I don't believe the size of each is a factor. Suggestions?

Comment: Thank you! Much faster than it was before. Can you explain why?

Comment: Because a) each file is now read just once, b) HTML generation occurs only once for all output, and c) you avoid repeated string concatenation and instead collect the lines in a list.